# Rails 4.2 Custom Error Page for Sidekiq When Missing ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

In our app, we have Sidekiq and have modified the `sidekiq.rb` file to have it require authentication to view the page.

`sidekiq.rb`

```
Sidekiq::Web.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  [user, password] == [ENV['SIDEKIQ_USER'], ENV['SIDEKIQ_PASSWORD']]
end
```

We want to have an error page set up for whenever the ENVs above are missing it will let us know specifically that the missing ENVs are the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: check the Sidekiq web code, open its base controller class and write a before action to render an error page when error happens.

Solution 2: write a conditional route, show the error page when error happens

Solution 3: throw errors in sidekiq.rb, so your server wont startup successfully, you will not need an error page anymore. I think the last one is the best, because this is just internal page to be viewed by few people, and probably only you, its better to find the problem as soon as possible.